# How to write forEach function for JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I want to write a forEach function for finding out data in my JSON
Case:

```
 [[{ {"Plan-Name = "qwe" , "plan_data" = "10"}
          {"Plan-Name = "asd" , "plan_data" = "10"}
          {"Plan-Name = "wrt" , "plan_data" = "10"}
      }]]
```

I want to search wrt and print its plan_data
and I have a Current plan = wrt, so if the current plan matches with Plan_name then print its Plan_data
I for my current plan responseJson[0][0]['cuurent_plan']
and for Plan_name responseJson[2]

Comment: this doesn't appear to be valid json - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Shru_v, what is your expected output ?

Comment: I am fetching the JSON from API it is in nested array so the first part my details which has the current plan:  HTIL9 in the same API there is specific Plan_name and Plan_data and there are around 50 plans so i want to do is if my current plan is - HTIL9 then i wanted to find the plan details of HTIL9 which is from index [2]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the JSON is invalid, if it's a valid JSON then you can do as below for your desired result.

```
const getPlanData = (planData, planName: string) => {
  const planInfo = planData.find((plan) => plan["Plan-Name"] === planName);

  return planInfo;
}

const apIResponse = [[

  { "Plan-Name": "qwe", "plan_data": "11" },
  { "Plan-Name": "asd", "plan_data": "22" },
  { "Plan-Name": "wrt", "plan_data": "33" }

]
]
const planValue = getPlanData(apIResponse[0], 'wrt')
console.log('res', planValue);
```